# Devuelve NoneType al llamar una función

Tags: python, flask

Tengo un endpoint en Flask que recibe una imagen que viene de un formulario, y tengo una función que captura la imagen y luego obtiene un código de barras. Dentro de la función puedo ver el código de barras que se obtiene, pero al llamar la función obtengo  Nonetype. Alguien me puede ayudar a cómo obtener el código que está en la función. También adjunto imagen de mi código. Muchas gracias.

Este es el endpoint

```
@app.route("/up", methods=['POST'])
def uplo():
 if request.method == 'POST':

  f = request.files['file']
  filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
  _file = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename) 
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
  f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) 

  Data = get_codigo(_file) # Llamo a la función
  print("get_codigo(_file) value:", get_codigo(_file)) # imprime get_codigo(_file) value: None
  print("Data value:", (Data)) # imprime Data value: None
  print("Datatype :", type(Data)) # imprime Datatype : <class 'NoneType'>
  
  return redirect(url_for('upload_file'))
```

Esta es la función

```
def get_codigo(_file):
  # get image and catch barcodeData
  try:
    image = cv2.imread(_file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    width = 1200 
    height = 600 
    dim = (width, height)

    image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(image)

    for barcode in barcodes:
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcodeType = barcode.type
        text = "{} ({})".format(barcodeData, barcodeType)
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
       
        if barcodeData is not None:
          print("The code is:", barcodeData) # imprime The code is: 0094115
          print("datatype code:", type(barcodeData)) # imprime datatype code: <class 'str'>
        else:
          print("The code no catched")  
  except OSError as error:
        print(error) 
        flash(str(error))  
        return barcodeData  # return code catched
```

Comment: No debería estar el `return barcodeData` fuera del `except`? (incluso al final del `try` tendría más sentido)

Comment: Si, tienes mucha razón. Ahora si puedo obtener el resultado esperado. Muchas gracias @abulafia.

Comment: @abulafia, sabes cómo acceder a la variable `barcodeData` desde otro endpoint?, ya que necesito enviar otra foto desde otro endpoint y renombrarla con ese mismo código